# Don't have sound anymore after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, unity, sound, upgrade

I just upgraded my ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and now I don't have sound anymore.
Also I tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863271) but unfortunately was unsuccessful . 
Any idea ?
I have a " VIA "sound card , P7H55 Main board , intel 870 (Core i7 ) processor .
here is my lspci -nn | grep Audio output :

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 06)

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be4] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Could you provide us some more details on your hardware setup, particularly with regards to audio?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lspci -nn | grep Audio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found my question answer . 
here is a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) you can see if you have same one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure whether it will help you or not...but I tried this solution after installing Ubuntu 11.04...and it worked for me...give it a try...

http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/06/how-to-solve-no-sound-through-laptop-integrated-speakers-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: it does not work !do you have better one ?

Comment: no buddy...that thing worked for me and i wrote the steps in a post as a future refernce for myself as well as others...

Comment: OK your ubuntu is 11.04 but mine is 11.10. I had no problem in 11.04 all began from upgrading to oneric !